# Load url into AJAX instead of on click and parse results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a webscraping technique all worked out in PHP until I found out that the platform I was developing it on (iOS via phone gap) didn't support PHP. I found a solution though, via JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $('#target');
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
    doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
  });
  function doAjax(url){
    if(url.match('^http')){
      $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                encodeURIComponent(url)+
                "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
        function(data){
          if(data.results[0]){
            var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
            container.html(data);
          } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
            container.html(errormsg);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      $('#target').load(url);
    }
  }
  function filterData(data){
    data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
    return data;
  }
});
```

The way the URL is loaded is by clicking a link and it get's the `href` of it and populates `url` (at least I think). I want the url to be static though, such as `http://website.com` and being pre populated. I tried replacing all `doAjax(url)` with `doAjax('http://website.com)` but that doesn't seem to work and I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Another problem with the new JS script is that I want to be able to parse the results and only show the `table` element. In PHP, I did this using:

```
data =  $html->find('table');
echo $data[1];
```

What would the equivalent be in javascript of that PHP function?

On a side note, I was considering splitting this up into two posts, but I thought that would be too many posts for tonight :)

**Edit: First problem was solved by @nnnnnn in the comments.**

Comment: If you're saying the above code works when the links are clicked (via the click handler calling your `doAjax()` function), but you also want to automatically call it for `'http://website.com'` without having to click, just add `doAjax('http://website.com');` to the end of your document.ready function. By the way, how is use of JSONP "webscraping"?

Comment: Thank you, that solves the first problem. And I only call it that because that's how I googled it, going from PHP to JS. Didn't know there was a more appropriate name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying the above code works when the links are clicked (via the click handler calling your `doAjax()` function), but you also want to automatically call it for `'http://website.com'` without having to click, just add `doAjax('http://website.com');` to the end of your document.ready function.

As far as extracting just a particular table from the response, within your ajax callback function you can create a jQuery object from the returned data, and then use jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to extract the part you care about, and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add that part to your container element:

```
  function(data){
    if(data.results[0]){
      var fullResponse = $(filterData(data.results[0])),
          justTable = fullResponse.find("table");
      container.append(justTable);
    } else {
      var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
      container.html(errormsg);
    }
  }
```

Note that the selector for `.find()` may need more information to select specifically the table you are talking about. Not sure if `"table:first"` would do it, or if that table has an id attribute you could use instead: `.find("#thetableidhere")`, or...?

Comment: This works great. Question, the page results in a lot of 404's for images that aren't being loaded. Is there anyway to get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part try this:

```
function doAjax(url) {
    url = url || 'http://website.com';   // fallback to str if url isnt defined

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

for the second part try (this assuming `data.results[0]` is where the raw html is):

```
$(data.results[0]).find('table');   // may have to use .filter() if node is in root
```

Comment: I ended up solving the first problem by what "nnnnnn" said in the comments. For the second solution, where would I place that?

Comment: After `filterData()` in the `$.getJSONP()` callback function

Comment: I put it up on jsFiddle. Is that the correct location? http://jsfiddle.net/5Mgur/